# ag-grid is not populating inside a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm new in using agGrid forgive me if you find something silly. So before this I was using Kendo Grid on angularjs but we thought to switch to some other grid so we are trying agGrid right now.

Below is the a sample of aggrid which is working fine and everything works. But, When i move my grid options inside a function which will be getting called on button click I'm getting **WARNING - grid options for ag-Grid not found. Please ensure the attribute ag-grid points to a valid object on the scope.**

I'm not able to understand what is the problem because inside this function kendo grid options are working fine and kendo grid is getting populated but I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong with the agGrid.

Kindly help me.

```
function abc($rootScope,$scope, $state, $stateParams, $timeout, Upload, baseURL, $cookieStore, $log, errorCheckFactory) {
    var columnDefs = [
        {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
        {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
        {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
    ];

    var rowData = [
        {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
        {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
        {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
    ];

    $scope.gridOptions2 = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData: rowData,
        enableFilter: true,
        enableColResize: true,
        enableSorting: true,
        groupHeaders: true,
        rowHeight: 22,
        //onModelUpdated: onModelUpdated,
        suppressRowClickSelection: true

    };
```

}

Comment: Have you find its solution. I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @ranjeet8082 check your bindings as i said in my answer.

Comment: hi, @ranjeet8082 u can Open the Grid At the time of Click a button , you can write  "gridOptions" in side the function. So u can load Html Also At that Time using ng-if first you can hide the html click only u can load html and then in options also load at the click function so u dont get any error. u can check with this plunker.  http://plnkr.co/edit/247nVYxwNmOXdHvutJNm?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

If the grid does not foud your gridOptions that surely means you have a typo in your html template

Check your hml template it must have

```
ag-grid="gridOptions2"
```

Note : if you use a controller with the controllerAs way, you have to bind variables on this and not on $scope.

If it's not this add, your html and your route/state/whatever definition of the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

This is angular-grid binding issue. check your scope variable gridOptions.

grid options function:

```
var columnDefs = [
  {displayName: "Make", field: "make"},
  {displayName: "Model", field: "model"},
  {displayName: "Price", field: "price"},
  {displayName: "Price2 ", field: "price2"},
  {displayName: "Test 4", field: "test4"},
  {displayName: "Test 5", field: "test5"},
  {displayName: "Test 6", field: "test6"},
];

var rowData = [
  {make: "Toyota Toyota Toyota Toyota Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000, price2: 145, "Test 4": "Test 4", "Test 5": "Test 5", "Test 6": "Test 6"},
  {make: "Acura", model: "Celica", price: 35000, price2: 145, "Test 4": "Test 4", "Test 5": "Test 5", "Test 6": "Test 6"}
];

vm.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: rowData  
};
```

Working Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/VRnwnXi6fzyaoJJ1YHOx?p=preview

```
Correct binding : <div angular-grid="main.gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="width: 100%"></div>
```

Error Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/zb4Vc2lw5VzRzYwsfhL7?p=preview

```
In-Correct Binding : <div angular-grid="main.gridOptions2" class="ag-fresh" style="width: 100%"></div>
```

We changed binding from gridOptions to gridOptions2 and it's giving us  warning : VM769 angular-grid.js:1 WARNING - grid options for Angular Grid not found. Please ensure the attribute angular-grid points to a valid object on the scope.

I think this should clear doubts.

Answer (score 0):

@ranjeet8082 You can Open the Grid At the time of Click a button, you can write "gridOptions" in side the function. So you can load Html Also At that Time using ng-if first you can hide the html click only you can load html and then in options also load at the click function so you don't get any error. You can check with this plunker.

```
<div ng-if="vm.gridOptions"  angular-grid="vm.gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="width: 100%"></div>
```

[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/247nVYxwNmOXdHvutJNm?p=preview)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.